# Figure out whether a number is all 1's or all 0's

Tags: bit-manipulation

I've got a binary number and a mask. The mask is some number of 1's followed by all 0's (ie, 11111100000). I need to figure out whether the digits of the first number corresponding to the 1 bits in the mask are either all 1s or all 0s, and I want to do this without doing any branching, and in as few instructions as possible. Also, due to language constraints (I'm not writing this in C), I can't treat booleans as numbers, so `(i&mask) == 0 | (i&mask)^mask == 0` won't work.

For example, if I have:

```
i =    0b11110001
mask = 0b11100000
```

...then it's true. Also if I have:

```
i =    0b00000001
mask = 0b11110000
```

...then it's true. But if I have:

```
i =    0b11011001
mask = 0b11110000
```

...then it's false.

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. No attempts yourself?

Comment: Try `xor`ing to start with...

Comment: `x & mask == 0` gives all 0, `(x & mask) ^ mask == 0` gives all 1

Comment: @MagicMan - my failed attempts will not be useful to anyone.

Comment: Sorry, @Heuster, I should have clarified - I'm in a language that doesn't allow you to treat booleans as numbers.

Comment: Does this language not produce a boolean from `<expr> == 0`?

Comment: It does, but I can't do bitwise arithmetic with booleans, only logical operators, which carry the weight of branching.

Comment: No such bitwise arithmetic between booleans is being suggested that I can see. `i` is a number, `mask` is a number, and `0` is a number.

Comment: Yes, but I need to figure out whether the masked bits are all 0's *or* all 1's. That "or" is what I'm unable to figure out without making it a logical or.

Comment: So apparently this is a language that doesn't have default operations on numbers. Could you then exactly specify what operations are there? Answering without knowing the constraints is more like guessing...

Comment: It's Go. It has bitwise operations (shift, xor, complement, etc) on numbers, and comparison operators. However, comparison operators return booleans, and the type system does not allow booleans to be treated as numbers (so you can't apply bitwise operators to them).

Comment: Does `number1 & number2` not return a number, when number1 and number2 are numbers, or does `number == 0` not return a boolean?

Comment: @immibis - `number1 & number2` returns a number and `number == 0` returns a boolean.

Comment: so what's the problem? `(number & number) == number` returns a boolean. `(number & number) ^ number == number` returns a boolean, and `boolean || boolean` returns a boolean.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - what do `and_result` and `xor_result` stand for? And this is very performance-critical code.

Comment: Actually i see you have `boolean | boolean` in your post. If Go is like C in this aspect, then `|` is bitwise OR and `||` is logical OR. You want logical OR.

Comment: @immibis - because of performance concerns, I want to avoid logical `&&` and logical `||` (because of the branching).

Comment: instead of 'a == 0 || b == 0` use `(a | b) == 0`

Comment: @immibis - what would that be written out? That is, what are `a` and `b`?

Comment: Actually I got it wrong, `(a | b) == 0` is equivalent to `a == 0 && b == 0` - note `&&` not `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that I have all the requirements clear now:

As said, given a number `x` and a mask `m`, we know that:

```
x & m == 0
```

if (and only if) all relevant bits of `x` are 0 and

```
(x & m) ^ m == 0
```

if (and only if) all relevant bits of `x` are 1.

Apparently, you don't want

```
(x & m == 0) || ((x & m) ^ m == 0)
```

because that could be too slow. However, we could use the simple math trick that

```
a * b == 0 if (and only if) a == 0 || b == 0
```

---

That is, your code could be

```
y = x & m
result = (y * (y ^ m)) == 0
```